# Passing callback objects to WCF service methods

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to pass callback objects (with callback methods) to a wcf service method?

Let's presume i have the following class:

```
class Callback
{
     public Callback(){}
     public int GetSomeData(int param)
     {
       return param;
     }
}
```

Is it possible somehow to make a call like :

```
WCFServiceProxy proxy = new WCFServiceProxy();
Callback myCallback = new Callback();
proxy.SomeMethod(myCallback);
```

and have the service call GetSomeData() implemented on the client side?
Or what would be a working solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

see [Duplex Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.  You have to define a secondary interface that serves as the callback contract.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void InvokeCallback();
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(ICallback)]
public interface IContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoSomething();
}
[ServiceBehavior]
public class MyService : IContract
{
    void DoSomething() { }
}
```

That's the basic approach.  I would strongly suggestion looking at Juval Lowy's website, [IDesign.net](http://www.idesign.net).  His downloads section has several examples of how to do this.

Comment: Finally i implemented it with a callback contract and it works great. What i also needed is to transfer data in my callback object and i've done that by adding [OperationContract] properties to the callback object.